# jQuery Click Selector Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, click

I am quite new to jQuery but I know my way around (ish).

I could try and explain it but it is easier to show you a demo (http://codepen.io/georgearnall/pen/KjtAw).

I want it so that when a user clicks on the mobile navigation toggle the menu should slide in from the side. Then if the user wants to close the navigation they can just tap anywhere on the page content (.page-wrap) and it will slide away again.

My problem is that the classes added during the code do not seem to work in the javascript.

Also, if there is another more simple way of doing this feel free to share :)

Thanks for any help

Comment: Why would this get downvoted? (+1 for taking the time to include example code and to provide a well written explanation)

Comment: I don't see style classes defined with the name `active` and `unactive`... Nothing will happen if no such class exists.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Event delegation my friend. Your binding click events to classes that get added dynamically, try changing your click handlers to the following syntax:

```
$(document).on("click", ".active .page-wrap", function() {
```

Here's a demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HJfxE

Comment: NB: always bind on the most specific enclosing element that you can, for efficiency.  It's rarely `document`.

Comment: Thanks this works well. In your opinion, is this the best way to tackle this problem ?

Comment: If there is a container around what you are clicking, then replace `document` with that container. But yes, this would be the way to solve this.